# Quadratic spline and quadratic interpolation

Tags: analysis, interpolation

I am trying to understand what is the difference between quadratic spline and quadratic interpolation.  Thank you for any help and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quadratic spline is a piecewise continuous curve where each segment is a quadratic polynomial. Quadratic interpolation means given a set of data points find a quadratic spline that goes thru all the points.

Comment: Thank you for and answer.  If I could choose which one would be best to use?  The point is, I am developing an application in C# and I am using a library called Math.Net.  In that library Quadratic interpolation is not available only Quadratic spline is available.  I created a Quadratic interpolation function, which seems to work.  But, is worth to understand Quadratic spline and implement it using that libray?

Comment: There is no harm to learn about the QuadraticSpline function and compare against your function if you have spare time.